# Count and total repeating occurrences of a unique values in DataGridView column

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, winforms

**EDIT** Question originally: Count and total repeating occurrences of a number in a specific array position - i.e. how many 0's in array[34].

**Changed to** Count and total repeating occurrences of a unique values in DataGridView column

### **This is because I feel I asked the wrong question and the new one gives a more accurate sense of what I was looking for**

This is pretty much exactly what I wanted: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/421557/Counting-Unique-Products-in-a-DataGridView-and-Dis

I obviously could have described the question much better.

I have a byte array populated with a random-access file, I would like to count the amount of times, let's say, 0 or 127 occurs in a certain position. At the moment I can count the amount of successful matches to several numbers but the problem is totalling it. I have tried this: (unsurprisingly does not work)

```
if (array[34] == 0)
{
    Label_a.Text = "abc";
}

int res_a = Regex.Matches(array[34].ToString(), "0").Count;
```

If I create a MessageBox with res_a, it recognises if it's a 0 or not by displaying a set message. But I would like to count and total the amount of occurrences in the background where the data totalled is going to be populated into a chart. General layout of current code:

```
// FileStream
// BinaryReader
// While length of file is larger than 0
// FileStream.Seek
// Foreach loop for array
// GET COUNT AND TOTAL HERE!
```

**For example, I import a file with 4 records with different status' where status code 127 is repeated 3 times and 0 is just once. I want to get THIS information - how many times it has occurred!**

[image]

Another example, this file has 12 records where status code 127 is repeated 6 times and 0 is 6 too:-

[image]

Comment: Your framework version supports Linq?

Comment: Oh! Yes, I'm using .NET Framework 3.5.

Comment: Your use of strings here looks suspicious. It seems that you are converting numeric values to strings and using regex to test equality against numbers stated as strings. A few questions: Why are you using Regex here when you're not using any specific regex feature? What's in your array (what type does it have)?

Comment: I didn't really know where to start so just used Regex, not suprised it doesn't work. The array is populated with data from a .bin file, each element is then decoded - to string, int, datetime, long...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment to L.B., I understand that you want to count the number of occurences of  each "status" value, so I would try something like this:

```
int[] vals = new int[10] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1 };
var res = vals.GroupBy(v => v).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

`res` now holds a Dictionary where each KeyValuePair has a Key representing a Status code, and a Value representing the number of time this Status code is in the array.

You can now test a Status code's number of appearance like this:

```
int Code1;
res.TryGetValue(1, out Code1); // testing for Status code 1
```

And so on.

Cheers

Comment: @lornasw I appreciate that you want to help people by fixing their code, but on Stack Exchange you shouldn't edit code unless it is yours. A better option would be to comment on the post to tell the author that their code is wrong.

Comment: Noted, thank you. There is a double variable declaration for the same value on the same line @LucMorin

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do something like this?

```
var countOf0s = array.Count(x => x == 0);
```

Comment: I'm sure that just counts throughout the entire array when I just want it to count through a single element/position?

Comment: @lornasw, Unclear what you are asking there can be only **one** number at a single position.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't go into enough detail - I have a DataGridView table which is populated by a random access .bin file. When I select a row record, fields are then populated with data that doesn't appear on the table. As I loop through a file, there are several values for a position. For instance, I select row 24 with the status "0" and then selected row "13" with the status "13" and so on throughout the file. What I would like to do is count and total the amount of times "0" appears and "13".